# Undeclared variable receiving a function in a Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting started with Angular JS and i'm working on tutorial i found on internet :
http://www.sitepoint.com/user-authenication-mean-stack/

In a service there are 3 undeclared variables receiving a function and i don't understand this syntax despite my researches.

code :

```
register = function(user) {
  return $http.post('/api/register', user).success(function(data){
    saveToken(data.token);
  });
};
```

The code for the whole service:

```
(function () {

  angular
    .module('meanApp') // service qui dépend de ce module ?
    .service('authentication', authentication);

  // $inject : To allow the minifiers to rename the function parameters and still be able to inject the right services, the function needs to be annotated with the $inject property. The $inject property is an array of service names to inject.
  // https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

  authentication.$inject = ['$http', '$window'];

  function authentication ($http, $window) {


    var saveToken = function (token) {
      $window.localStorage['mean-token'] = token;
    };

    var getToken = function () {
      return $window.localStorage['mean-token'];
    };

    var isLoggedIn = function() {
      var token = getToken();
      var payload;

      if(token){
        payload = token.split('.')[1];
        payload = $window.atob(payload); will decode a Base64 string
        payload = JSON.parse(payload);

        return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    };

    var currentUser = function() {
      if(isLoggedIn()){
        var token = getToken();
        var payload = token.split('.')[1];
        payload = $window.atob(payload);
        payload = JSON.parse(payload);
        return {
          email : payload.email,
          name : payload.name
        };
      }
    };

    //An interface between the Angular app and the API, to call the login and register end-points and save the returned token. This will use the Angular $http service
    register = function(user) {
      return $http.post('/api/register', user).success(function(data){
        saveToken(data.token);
      });
    };

    login = function(user) {
      return $http.post('/api/login', user).success(function(data) {
        saveToken(data.token);
      });
    };

    logout = function() {
      $window.localStorage.removeItem('mean-token');
    };

    return {
      currentUser : currentUser,
      saveToken : saveToken,
      getToken : getToken,
      isLoggedIn : isLoggedIn,
      register : register,
      login : login,
      logout : logout
    };
  }


})();
```

Thank you for your explanations

Comment: its simple here authentication function returning an object you can use that object in controllers like :- "authentication.register"

Comment: "there are 3 undeclared variables receiving a function " Which ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code example is inconsistent with declaring its variables. It's considered best practice to use the `var` statement when declaring a variable, but when not running strict mode the `var` can be omitted.

You generally should use `'use strict'` at the top of your javascript file, so undeclared variables won't be permitted as the browser is running the JS in strict mode.

something like this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('meanApp') // service qui dépend de ce module ?
    .service('authentication', authentication);
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var register = function(user) {
      return $http.post('/api/register', user).success(function(data){
        saveToken(data.token);
      });
    };

  var  login = function(user) {
      return $http.post('/api/login', user).success(function(data) {
        saveToken(data.token);
      });
    };

   var logout = function() {
      $window.localStorage.removeItem('mean-token');
    };

put var and check it
```